# Cell background and accessory

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview, accessoryview

I am trying to set the cell background of my UITableViewCells but I am struggling with the background color of the UIAccessoryView. It does not change.

Can anyone help me make the background color of the UIAccessoryView transparent (or actually any other color)?

This is my code

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

if(indexPath.row % 2) {
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
else {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Here is an image illustrating the issue

[image: UIAccessoryView does not change background color.]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'll need to set the `backgroundView` property of the UITableViewCell.  For example:

```
UIView* myBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myCell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
```

If you want something more fancy, like a red gradient background, you would implement a subclass of UIView that draws a gradient in `drawRect:`, and use it as the backgroundView.

You can also set the `selectedBackgroundView` property if you want a custom look for a selected table cell.

Comment: Awesome! That works and is so much easier! Good idea with gradient and a `selectedBackgroundView` Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks a lot... Got stuck for a long time here and your answer was the first one to solve it. :)

Answer (score 5):

In function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use following code

```
cell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[reference for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484511/altering-the-background-color-of-cell-accessoryview-and-cell-editingaccessoryvie)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it in custom class of `UITableViewCell` you can just use:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

changing background inside of `awakeFromNib()` or `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` doesn't work!