# Setting reorder icon to be transparent UITableViewCells - moverowat function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any way to set the icon for reorder to be transparent?
Here is a screenshot of the issue.
[image]

Cell has a view, which has this gray color as background

Comment: In cell for row, use this `cell.selectionStyle = .None`

Comment: Did you check this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484566/2618071 If your background color is already set in the good place, then you can maybe check the background color of the AccessoryView

Comment: cell.selectionStyle = .None doesn't work thanks for trying, thanks for that article id solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.contentView.superview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Fixed my issue thanks to @Toldy