# With DarkMode the ContentView of a cell is not selected on touch, only the AccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

As per title, with darkMode the selection of a grouped cell is not working as expected: the ContentView of a cell is not selected on touch, only the AccessoryView. Everything works fine on the LightMode.

I have changed the background color of both the cell and its content view to Default (Table Cell Grouped Background Color) in the StoryBoard.
If it can help, the background color of the accessoryView is made equal to the background color of the Content View in the `willDisplay cell` function

```
favouriteCell.contentView.superview?.backgroundColor = favouriteCell.contentView.backgroundColor
```

[image]

Comment: or maybe it's working but your cell color in darkMode is the same as the selection color.

Comment: @KeshuR. no, it is a different color. It is the same color of the accessoryView background color where you can see the selection

Comment: can you please show your code ???

Comment: @NayanDave the only code is `favouriteCell.contentView.superview?.backgroundColor = favouriteCell.contentView.backgroundColor` and I have changed the background color of both the cell and its content view to Default (Table Cell Grouped Background Color) in the StoryBoard

Comment: @KeshuR. I have added a screenshot of the cell selection

Comment: where have you put that code ?? and it does not make sense..

Comment: @NayanDave the code is in  `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and I have added it to force the accessoryView to have the same background color as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484511/altering-the-background-color-of-cell-accessoryview-and-cell-editingaccessoryvie

Comment: is your `UITableView` is static or dynamic ? , if it's dynamic then what have you wrote in the `cellForRowAt` delegate function ???

Comment: @NayanDave it is static, grouped

Comment: and you've added accessory view with `storyboard` or ????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206714/discussion-between-nayan-dave-and-gianni).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to a bug: the app doesn't register background color changes of the cell if done in the storyboard